# WPF: how can I style DataGridTextColumn in one style class?

Tags: wpf, styles, datagridtextcolumn

I try to stylize DataGridTextColumn setting Header and Cell styles separatly:

```
   <Style x:Key="headerStyle">
            <Setter Property="DataGridColumnHeader.Background" ... />
   ...

    <Style x:Key="cellStyle">
            <Setter Property="DataGridCell.Background" ... />
  ...


<DataGrid>
  <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn 
          HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey='headerStyle'}" 
          CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey='cellStyle'}" ... />
```

Can I stylize DataGridTextColumn Header, Cell and other properties in one style declaration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i can tell that might be impossible since `DataGridTextColumn` does not provide a Template or Style property of its own which could be used to set the other styles collectively.

Comment: It supplies an ElementStyle property which *should* work, but it doesn't  :-(

Comment: @HiredMind: [`ElementStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.elementstyle.aspx) if for the cells not the column itself.